# I'm trying to do a search function for my program to search the record from my text file

Tags: c++

This function is to count the number of lines in my text file

```
int counter()
{
    int counter = 0;
    ifstream infile("books.txt", ios::in);
    if (infile.is_open() && !infile.eof())
    {
        char line[200];
        while (!infile.eof())
        {
            infile.getline(line, 200, '\n');
            counter++;
        }
        infile.close();
    }
    else
        cout << "File is not open\n";
    return counter;
}
```

This is my search function where it reads data in from text file "books.txt" into array of struct - DATA book. But I couldn't figure which part is wrong and makes it show "Record not found" even if I entered the correct input. DATA book is my array of struct to store whatever is in the text file and categorized them into members like isbn code, author, title etc.

```
int search(DATA book[])
{
    char search[200];
    int i = 0;
    bool found = false;

    cout << "Enter ISBN Code/title/author to SEARCH: ";
    cin.getline(search, 200);
    //cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    int count = counter();
    while (i < count && !found)
    {
        if (strcmp(search, book[i].isbn_code) == 0 || strcmp(search, book[i].author) == 0 || strcmp(search, book[i].title) == 0)
        {
            found = true;
            cout << "ISBN Code: " << book[i].isbn_code << "\nAuthor: " << book[i].author << "\nTitle: " << book[i].title << "\nPublisher: " << book[i].publisher
                << "\nYear Published: " << book[i].year_published << "\nQuantity: " << book[i].quantity << fixed << setprecision(2)
                << "\nPrice: " << book[i].price << "\nRack: " << book[i].loc.rack << "\nLevel number: " << book[i].loc.level_no << endl << endl;
        }
        else
            i++;
    }
    if (!found)
        cout << "Record not found.\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You open a file and then you don't read anything from it. I doubt that's what you want.

Comment: Hi, I've edited the code but it still doesn't work...

Comment: Actually do I still need to open my text file again to read in? I'm asking because I've did the reading file and storing into array of struct in my another function.

Comment: no... you should be able to remove anything to do with infile and just loop through your book[] array looking for the search buffer.

Comment: I'd suggest putting a few extra cout's in the program to ensure that count, search, and possibly the record you're looking at are what you think they are, and that found actually gets set to true when you expect it to.

Comment: exactly how do i loop through my book[] array? cuz i've removed anything to do with infile but it still doesn't work

Comment: int recordcount = sizeof(book[]) / sizeof(DATA); while (i < recordcount && !found) { ... } -- not necessarily the cleanest way, but it should work.

Comment: int recordcount = sizeof(book[WHAT SHOULD I INSERT HERE?]) / sizeof(DATA);

Comment: should just be sizeof(book).  You want the size of the entire array divided by the size of one element, which will give you the number of elements... sorry, wrote that up quickly and wasn't exactly clear on that.

Comment: oh its ok haha but may i know what is the function of this line?

Comment: It basically gives you the number of elements in the book array that's passed as a parameter.  You're passed an array and know that it's a certain data type (DATA), if you divide the size of the array by the size of the data type, you end up with the number of elements that are contained in the passed array.  As you had it, the "counter()" function seemed to be returning the number, but you didn't post that function so it's not clear how it figured out the count.

Comment: sorry for forgotten to include my counter function, i've included it now